# I am trying to create a very simple popup that brings info from a (point) geoJson attribute

Tags: popup, leaflet, geojson

I am using the following code and it just doesn't work!!! Working with a point geoJson.

This same type of code DOES work for a polygon geoJson a few steps after.

js:

```
 var points2 = L.geoJson(points2,{onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
 layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popup);}}).addTo(map);
```

---

the relevant geojson:

```
var points2 = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features":

[
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-73.997208,40.743771]},"properties":{"cartodb_id":2,"description":"Private home","popup":"Casa Señora Arnao (Bernardo's 1st abode in NYC)","address":"228 West 22nd Street"}},

{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-73.926637,40.858235]},"properties":{"cartodb_id":5,"description":"Urban scene","popup":"Couples kissing openly - \"I quickly realized that our presence didn’t matter to them….what a difference between our customs back home and the behavior of Puerto Rican men and women in New York!”","address":"Park at 191st Street and St-Nicholas Avenue"}},

{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-73.95678,40.805015]},"properties":{"cartodb_id":4,"description":"Private home","popup":"Casa Familia León","address":"116th Street and Manhattan Avenue"}},

{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-73.949677,40.797255]},"properties":{"cartodb_id":7,"description":"Political/Cultural meeting place","popup":"Park Palace","address":"3-5 West 110th Street"}},

{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-73.9467,40.790554]},"properties":{"cartodb_id":8,"description":"Political/Cultural meeting place","popup":"Harlem Terrace","address":"210 East 104th Street"}},

{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-73.948755,40.793271]},"properties":{"cartodb_id":9,"description":"Political/Cultural meeting place","popup":"Harlem Educational Center","address":"106th Street (between Park and Madison Aves)"}}

]}
```

---

What could be possible cause of the error and How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The code you provided works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ujp0swns/1/  Are you sure you didn't miss any issues in OP?

Comment: The markers come up, but no pop-up. The map works as such, but I get no popup.

Comment: what do you mean by OP?

Comment: Your original post. In the fiddle I've provided popups are shown.

Comment: Don't think so. Where could it be? How could part of the script work (drawing) while the popups part doesnt work?

Comment: Also, what version of lealflet do you use?